# How can i align the tooltip above the sorter icon? I am using antd

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd framework for making a table with sorter column. How can I make the tooltip aligned above the sorter icon? Here's the snippet of my UI.

[image]

I added this prop inside the column, date.

```
showSorterTooltip={{title: 'Click to sort', placement: 'topRight', arrowPointAtCenter: false, autoAdjustOverflow: true}}
```

Answer (score 0):

showSorterTooltip accepts Tooltip props.
Try adding 'align:{ offset: [x, y] }' in showSorterTooltip. You can adjust x and y: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21337

This does not work after antd 5.3.0: https://ant.design/docs/blog/tooltip-align

Comment: Your method requires calculating the position of the up and down arrows for each column in the table. The positional parameters are variable, and you should provide code to calculate the position of the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

ShowSorterTooltip accept Tooltip tips,

**align: {offset: [x, y]  }}** />

Calculate the position of the arrow on the table column, and then use it to offset the x and y

Comment: it is working though, i think it is not advisable for doing responsive ui

Comment: antd Table does not have better API, so I think that my answer is a relatively good idea at present.